# Continue CSS3 Keyframes Animation on Hover / Stop Repeat on Hover

Tags: javascript, css, animation, hover, css-animations

I have a CSS3 animation set up and I just want to change the box-shadow color on hover. However, when I do it, the animation abruptly resets. Is there any way to continue the seamless animation on hover with no jumping? If I need to use javascript or jquery, that's fine, but I'd prefer if there was a CSS3 solution. Any help is appreciated.

```css
table {
    max-width:1000px!important;
    padding:15px;
    word-wrap:
    break-word;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border: 7px solid #454ce9;
    animation: glowing 5000ms infinite;
}

table:hover {
    animation: glowing2 5000ms infinite;
}


@keyframes glowing {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #e9458a; }
    40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a; }
    60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #e9458a;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #e9458a; }
    40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a; }
    60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #e9458a;}
}

@keyframes glowing2 {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #ad45e9; }
    40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ad45e9; }
    60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ad45e9;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #ad45e9;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing2 {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #ad45e9; }
    40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ad45e9; }
    60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ad45e9;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #ad45e9;}
}
```

```html
<table border="10"><tr><td colspan="2">Hover over me</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do hover animations, `transition` is a great feature that reverse the animation when unhover.

```css
table {
    max-width:1000px!important;
    padding:15px;
    word-wrap:
    break-word;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border: 7px solid #454ce9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #e9458a;
    transition: box-shadow 2500ms;
}

table:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a;
}
```

```html
<table border="10"><tr><td colspan="2">Hover over me</td></tr></table>
```

---

If to still use `animation`, use `animation-play-state` and `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to make it run when hovered and keep state when unhovered

In below sample I used their longhand properties, though they can be added to the shorthand, i.e. like this for the *animation-fill-mode* `animation: glowing 5000ms infinite forwards;`.

I would keep `animation-play-state` as longhand, as it won't work on IE (and, if I remember correct, on older versions of Edge).

*Note, negative `<blur-radius>` values on `box-shadow` is not allowed (and I noticed it won't work on IE/Edge but it did on Chrome)*

```css
table {
    max-width:1000px!important;
    padding:15px;
    word-wrap:
    break-word;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border: 7px solid #454ce9;
    animation: glowing 5000ms infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;          /*  persist state  */
    animation-play-state: paused;           /*  pause the animation  */
}

table:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;           /* play the animation  */
}


@keyframes glowing {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #e9458a; }
    40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a; }
    60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #e9458a;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes glowing {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #e9458a; }
    40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a; }
    60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #e9458a;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px #e9458a;}
}
```

```html
<table border="10"><tr><td colspan="2">Hover over me</td></tr></table>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

It is also possible to change color during the animation

```css
table {
    max-width:1000px!important;
    padding:15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border: 7px solid #454ce9;
    animation: glowing 5000ms infinite forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

table:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px red; }
    25% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px green;}
    75% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px yellow;}
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 0px red;}
}
```

```html
<table border="10"><tr><td colspan="2">Hover over me</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware that I can do this instead, but I want to keep that keyframe animation present because the effect is different from a simple transition and the continuous fade-in-and-out is the desired effect I want. I'm still wondering if it's possible.

Comment: @Aquila As the other answer deleted its initial solution, I added it to mine, with some notes to make it work on IE/Edge.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answered my question more. There's just one more thing I'm wondering about: am I able to change the box-shadow color on hover with this solution or is that something that can't be done with CSS?

Comment: @Aquila Added a 3rd sample that also change color

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use this to stop it from jumping back once the animation is complete

```
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Also seems to have been answered here - [CSS Keyframe Animations on Hover - Animation Resetting with Mouse Movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344978/css-keyframe-animations-on-hover-animation-resetting-with-mouse-movement)

Comment: That other answer seems to be asking for something similar to me but the result isn't what I'm looking for. I want the animation to keep seamlessly repeating on hover instead of abruptly resetting. I also tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to be making a change. Am I implementing it incorrectly? https://jsfiddle.net/Lbu18j2a/